# JRuby: extend Java class with two methods that have the same name

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Good morning every body,
I am trying to extend an abstract Java class with two methods that have the same name. But only need to verride one of them.

Here is my Java code:

```
public abstract class ClientHandler extends Handler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    protected boolean disable = true;
    protected X509Certificate signatureCertificate;
    protected PrivateKey privateKey;
    protected Certificate[] signatureCertificationChain;

    //Constructeur 
    protected ClientHandler(boolean disable) {
        this.disable = disable;
    }

    private boolean handleMessage(VIHF vihf) {
        //This is the beginning of the method i am trying to redefine
        X509Certificate certificate = this.signatureCertificate
        String issuer = certificate.getSubjectDN().toString();
        //some code 
        ...
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        //some code
    }
  }
```

Here is my JRuby code

```
#To make parent attributes accessible from subclasses
class  ClientHandler
   field_accessor :disable, :signatureCertificate, :privateKey, :signatureCertificationChain
end

#first version referring to that post: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238734/jruby-calls-  the-wrong-method>

module RubyClientHandler
  class RClientHandler < ClientHandler
    handleMessage =  ClientHandler.java_method :handleMessage,    java.lang.Class.for_name(Java::ComSubFolder::VIHF)]

    def handleMessage(vihf)
        super(self.disableSignature)  #is this line ok or note?

        certificate = self.signatureCertificate    #do i need to use the "self" or the "@" ?
        issuer = certificate.getSubjectDN().toString()
        ...
    end
   end
end
```

With my first version when i try to use the "java_method", i am getting the following error:
"no method 'forName' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyModule) on Java::JavaLang::Class"

Then i have tried this second version of the RClientHandler class

Second version : referring to that post: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216636

```
 module RubyClientHandler
    class RClientHandler < ClientHandler
     def handleMessage(vihf)
         super          #line causing the error 
         klass = vihf.class

         if(klass.eql?(Java::ComSubFolder::VIHF) )
            self.java_send :handleMessage,[VIHF], vihf

            certificate = self.signatureCertificate
            issuer = certificate.getSubjectDN().toString()
            ...
         end
     end
   end
 end
```

With this second version i am getting the following Exception that is pointing the first line of the "handleMessage"

```
HANDLER_RAISED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Native Exception: 'class java.lang.StackOverflowError';     Message: null; StackTrace: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.jruby.proxy.com.sub.folder.ClientHandler$Proxy0.__super$handleMessage(Unknown Source)
```

Is this line with "super" calling the parent class constructor or the parent "handleMessage" method ?
Do i need some argument when calling "super" here according to the parent class constructor ?

Any help will be appreciate to tell me how can i extend this "ClientHandler" class by overriding only one (or the two) "handleMessage" method in JRuby.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, trying passing the name of Java class as a string:

```
java.lang.Class.for_name('Java::ComSubFolder::VIHF')
```

Update: Actually, that won't work, since that's the JRuby namespace, right? You need the Java path to the class.

Example:

```
> java.lang.Class.for_name('java.lang.StringBuffer')
=> #<Java::JavaLang::Class:0x628d2280> 
> java.lang.Class.for_name('java.util.ArrayList')
=> #<Java::JavaLang::Class:0x5057f57f>
```

Comment: I have tried to use the name of my class as string, but i am getting the following error

     NativeException (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sub/folder/VIHF):
  java/lang/Class.java:-2:in `forName0'
  java/lang/Class.java:169:in `forName'

Comment: How is your Java code provided to JRuby? In a jar file? If so, do you have that jar on your class path?